# Добавление в БД, winforms

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms

при вставке в таблицу происходит ошибка, не знаю что она означает, помогите пожалуйста Вот весь код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace NetDevice
{
    public partial class Record : Form
    {
        private SqlConnection db = null;
        private SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        public Record()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Record_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: данная строка кода позволяет загрузить данные в таблицу "netDivDataSet.Users". При необходимости она может быть перемещена или удалена.
            this.usersTableAdapter.Fill(this.netDivDataSet.Users);
            // TODO: данная строка кода позволяет загрузить данные в таблицу "netDivDataSet.Devices". При необходимости она может быть перемещена или удалена.
            this.devicesTableAdapter.Fill(this.netDivDataSet.Devices);
            db = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Netdb"].ConnectionString);
        }

        private void Clebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.txtId.Text = "";
            this.txtName.Items.Clear();
            this.txtRole.Items.Clear();
            this.txtEmail.Items.Clear();
            this.txtDevice.Items.Clear();
            this.txtNumber.Text = "";
            this.Dttxt.Text = "";
        }

        private void Insbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (this.txtName.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a Name...");
                }
                else if (this.txtRole.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a Pass...");
                }
                else if (txtEmail.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a Email...");
                }
                else if (txtDevice.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a Email...");
                }
                else if (txtNumber.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a Email...");
                }
                else
                {
                    string Name = txtName.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    string Role = txtRole.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    string Email = txtEmail.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    string Device = txtEmail.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    string Number = txtNumber.Text;
                    int number = Int32.Parse(Number);
                    DateTime selectedtime = Dttxt.Value;
                    string qry = "Insert into Records(Name, Role, Email, Device, Number, Date) values ('" + Name + "','" + Role + "','" + Email + "','" + Device +"','"+number+"','"+selectedtime+ "')";
                    cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, db);
                    db.Open();
                    if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Records add: " );
                    }
                    else
                        MessageBox.Show("User Registration failed with username:" + Name);
                    db.Close();
                    Clebtn_Click(sender, e);
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception exp)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Some Error Registratin: " + exp.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вот фото с ошибкой
[image: Извините что в фото, просто эта ошибка не копируется]

И у меня второй вопрос, у меня на форме есть datetimepicker правильно ли я добавляю значения из datetimepickera в мою таблицу Records я передаю в переменную DateTime selectedtime = Dttxt.Value; И названия этой переменной ввожу INSERT VALUES там в коде всё прописано. Заранее спасибо, мне очень нужна помощь, в первом вопросе эта ошибка, а во втором подсказка как можно занести данные в datetimepicker и если не сложно как потом вывести в datagridview

Comment: поди поле `Role` в базе имеет лимит на длину, а вы туда что то записать пытаетесь, что больше лимита.

Comment: Я проверил но по длине всё подходит, я беру все данные через combobox

Comment: какой тип и лимит поля в БД и что конкретно вы туда писать пытаетесь?

Comment: Тип поля nvarchar(20)

Comment: Поставьте 200 и проверьте ошибку